# How to show SLF4J logs of an RCP application in within the application?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, slf4j, logback

Obviously it's possible to write my own appender in Logback which sends the output to an `IConsole`. Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use [Eclipse plugin for logback](http://logback.qos.ch/consolePlugin.html)?

Comment: From download page: "Unfortunately, the console plugin is very much outdated. It expects logback version 0.9.9. It will be upgraded during the second semester of 2011."

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov, well, as a dirty hack, you can rebuild logback to make it show the version you want. Or there are some other reasons not to use it?

Comment: Presumably the problem is not with the version declared by Logback, but it actually isn't compatible with the current implementation. Otherwise they would have updated it long ago.

Comment: Current version on the download page is `logback-1.1.2`. And the     Logback Beagle Feature has version 1.1.4.201209042005.