# Listening for GUI availability in Eclipse RCP

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I want my plug-in to do something after the workbench opens and the GUI is available. Is there a way to do it? `IWorkbenchListener` only listens for workbench shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

Use `IWorkbench.addWindowListener(IWindowListener listener)` instead.

Comment: Tonny, I'm not sure if that will give you always the expected result, because it implies that PlatformUI.getWorkbench is not null, which can happen for instance in "earlyStartup" extension or in bundle-activators of bundles with a low start-level. IMHO there is no silver bullet getting notified when a GUI is available. @Alexey What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @TomSeidel As mentioned at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8026444/how-to-show-slf4j-logs-of-an-rcp-application-in-within-the-application I want to create a console view appender for Logback, and it doesn't make sense to start it before GUI is available. Of course, I _can_ start it earlier and test for workbench existence before logging if necessary, but it's less elegant.

Comment: You should have a loggin-datamodel where you're appender adds new objects. Your console should start listening to that datamodel when its activated, not earlier. Start listening in your overwritten org.eclipse.ui.console.MessageConsole.createPage(IConsoleView)

Comment: @TomSeidel I usually add these in the `WorkbenchAdvisor` or alternatively in an `Activator` in a plug-in with the startup extension point. In both cases, you are sure that the workbench already exists :-)

Answer (score 0):

Override  `ApplicationWorkBenchWindowAdvisor.postWindowOpen()`